# Load picture with native photo viewer

Tags: ios, native, photo, viewer

I've been looking around and I just couldn't find anything that really fits my (very simple) needs.

I have a `UIImage` (as a `NSData`, then file, then image) that is displayed, and I'd like to be able to tap it and display the native "show", that has the little box & arrow icon where you can decide wether you wanna save the picture, or share it by mail, facebook, twitter, and so on.

Wherever i've looked I only found a [great looking framework](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser) that clearly overkills my needs, or confusing information about `PHAssets` and `PHImageManager`.

I do not need to browse multiple photos, nor to see photos from albums. I just need to see my picture with the native "Share" button (box with outgoing arrow) and the native layout.

Is there such a thing available ? Without having to download a framework? Or should I just use the 5% of MWaterfall that i need?

Comment: +1 for this question, I'm trying to find such a solution as to just show native photo viewer. I only found developers use only library/framework to show it which makes me wonder isn't there any solution built-in in iOS for us to use right away? I'm still researching ...

Comment: Hey man, i looked for a while after I posted the question, and I ended up using EBPhoto library. It's fairly simple to use and does what I need it to do. (pinch, share, etc.) It does a little more than that (you can implement comments, tags, users, reports, etc.)
I don't think you can use the built-in photo viewer

Comment: Okay, thanks. I ended up using MWPhotoBrowser for now. Happy coding.

Comment: Great tool too :) Happy coding to you too!

Comment: I just found out that there's native one, very simple. I don't test it yet, but you might want to see. Use uiimagepickercontroller.